# Debian package changelog automation fill

Tags: continuous-integration, package, debian, deb

I have Continuous Integration system which builds some project. Now I would add automatic deb-package creation stage. But composing a .deb supposes changelog to be changed everytime.

So I have few questions:
1) How can I automatically set Git's comment and commit author to be exported to debchange 
utility?
2) How can versions/releases automatically should be changed?
3) How to avoid huge changelog (many commits per day will burn the brain
   of changelog reader person) by passing some minor versions?
4) If debian directory (with changelog, control and rules files) is out of repsitory - where should it be kept?

Answer (score 1):

You can use git-dch from git-buildpackage.